# Angular Formly Error Summary when using fieldGroups

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

Hopefully this will be a more generic Angular JS question rather than something specific to Angular Formly.

I've been following the framework provided [here](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/error-summary) for building an error summary on the angular formly form. All works well.....but!

In the example, their model is as follows:

```
vm.fields = [
  {
    key: 'picky',
    type: 'customInput',
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'Picky field...',
      placeholder: 'This is required and has a maxlength of 5 and minlength of 3',
      required: true,
      maxlength: 5,
      minlength: 3
    }
  },
  .....
  {
    key: 'ip',
    type: 'customInput',
    validators: {
      ipAddress: {
        expression: function(viewValue, modelValue) {
          var value = modelValue || viewValue;
          return /(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/.test(value);
        },
        message: '$viewValue + " is not a valid IP Address"'
      }
    },
    templateOptions: {
      label: 'IP Address',
      required: true,
      type: 'text',
      placeholder: '127.0.0.1',
    }
  }
];
```

Then, if we look at the HTML, we can see that these fields are being passed into the error summary as such:

```
<formly-error-summary form="vm.form" fields="vm.fields"></formly-error-summary>
```

For simple form structure, this works fine, but, if you want to use a Bootstrap layout, as described [here](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/bootstrap-specific/advanced-layout) then your model ends up looking something mine does:

```
vm.rentalFields = [
{
    template: '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><h3>About You</h3></div></div>'  
},
{
    className: 'row',
    fieldGroup: [
    {
        className: 'col-xs-6',
        type: 'customInput',
        key: 'first_name',
        templateOptions: {
            type: 'text',
            label: 'First Name',
            placeholder: 'Enter your first name',
            required: true
        }
    },
    {
        className: 'col-xs-6',
        type: 'customInput',
        key: 'last_name',
        templateOptions: {
            type: 'text',
            label: 'Last Name',
            placeholder: 'Enter your last name',
            required: true
        },
        expressionProperties: {
            'templateOptions.disabled': '!model.first_name'
        }   
    }
    ]
},
{
    template: '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><h3>License and Insurance Details</h3></div></div>',
    hideExpression: '!model.email'
}
.....
```

Now, when we pass in vm.rentalFields to the error summary, instead of accessing the fields, it instead just validates each object. I can get round this by doing something like:

```
<formly-error-summary form="vm.rentalForm" fields="vm.rentalFields[1].fieldGroup"></formly-error-summary>
```

This of course is not ideal since there will be fields in other field groups that I will want to validate, for proving the issue though it's fine for now. I have tried just passing in 'vm.rentalFields.fieldGroup' but as I suspected, that returns nothing.

So, is there a way I can recursively pass in all the fieldGroups within the vm.rentalField object or is this something that I should handle within the code of the Directive itself.

```
angular.module("formlyApp").directive('formlyErrorSummary', function() {
    return {
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        form: '=',
        fields: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'js/Directives/formly-error-summary.html',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      controller: function() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.getErrorAsList = getErrorAsList;
        console.log(vm.fields);
        function getErrorAsList(field) {
          return Object.keys(field.formControl.$error).map(function(error) {
            // note, this only works because the customInput type we have     defined.
            return field.data.getValidationMessage(error);
          }).join(', ');
        }
      }
};
});
```

---

**EDIT**

Ok, so, after taking advice from Ken below, I have been able to modify my formlyErrorSummary directive so that it now is at least able to get the errors for the model. This has numerous issues in it since the $scope.$watch is doing a deep level comparison and even on the first page load, the whole thing is fired 3 times! I've added in some rudimentary escapes to try and combat this and for now at least I have the errors, the next issue I have is within the HTML where I am call `ng-repeat="field in vm.fields"` which is effectively the same issue, so how would I work round this? Part of me is thinking of some anonymous object that would hold the fields message and whether or not is is valid and then parse that inside the HTML, but I'm not sure if this way of thinking is applicable to Angular?

```
controller: function($scope) {

var vm = this;

$scope.$watch('vm.fields', function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < vm.fields.length; i++)
        if(vm.fields[i].fieldGroup) {
            for(var j = 0; j < vm.fields[i].fieldGroup.length; j ++)
                if(vm.fields[i].fieldGroup[j].formControl) {
                    var err = getErrorAsList(vm.fields[i].fieldGroup[j]); 
                    if(err)
                        vm.getErrorAsList = err;
                }
        }
}, true);
```

---

**SOLUTION - POSSIBLY**

After much hacking around, I think I finally have this working so that the error messages are now displayed both inline and in a summary at the top.

My final directive function now creates an array each time it is run which will hold all of the error messages, it has to be flushed within the `$watch` otherwise when the field is valid, the error message will persist within the array so we simply rebuild the entire thing each time.....given I'm already using a deep level watch here, I'm hoping any performance hits will be negligible.

```
vm.errs = [];

$scope.$watch('vm.fields', function(){
    vm.errs = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < vm.fields.length; i++)
        if(vm.fields[i].fieldGroup) {
            for(var j = 0; j < vm.fields[i].fieldGroup.length; j ++)
                if(vm.fields[i].fieldGroup[j].formControl) {
                    var err = getErrorAsList(vm.fields[i].fieldGroup[j]); 
                    if(err)
                        if(vm.errs.indexOf(err) === -1)
                          vm.errs.push(err);
                }
        }
}, true);
```

Then, within the directives template, I had to remove the `vm.fields` reference as that was obviously not going to work in this approach. Since I knew that this summary would only be shown if the form was invlaid, I could remove so of the other checks that were being carried out and eventually ended up with the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="formly-error-summary bg-danger" ng-if="vm.form.$invalid">
            <div ng-repeat="err in vm.errs" class="color-error">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                <span>
                    {{err}}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm still not 100% happy with this, it gets the job done, but I'm not sure if it's the 'Angular' way of doing this and the fact I'm using `$scope.$watch` on the fields object is a little bit annoying to my developer OCD, but a solution it is all the same.

If anyone has any refinements or suggestions for improvements to this let me know please, still getting to grips with Angular but this has been a pretty fun learning experience!

Comment: I think the best thing you could do is simply pass the fields as `vm.fields` then in the directive you could handle getting all of the sub-field's errors yourself.

Comment: @kentcdodds thanks for the suggestion, the problem is at the moment, if I pass in just vm.fields, then the getErrorAsList function never fires, it only fires if I pass in a list with the fields already accessible

Comment: Try a `$scope.$watch('vm.fields')` then ;-)

Comment: When using a $watch on an array though, you have to use a deep watch and from some documentation, watching an entire array in this way can potentially have performance impacts. I also can't see how this gets round the original issue not being able to differentiate between the fieldgroups and the fields contained within?

Comment: I've edited the question with what I think is a possible solution, @kentcdodds, if you have any input on this I'd welcome it, not too sure if I have done this in the most efficient way with regards to formly, but it seems to work now none the less :)

Comment: You might consider not doing a deep watch, but instead pass a function to your `$watch` call and simply return what you're interested in. This could potentially lead to better performance because the fields objects have a lot of data in them.

Comment: @kentcdodds I think Jak's issue is a very common problem once you start to create some formly forms slightly more complicated than simple. So, why don't you guys (Jak?) consider posting this solution as an example in formly site too with a jsbin we can also fiddle with?

Comment: You'll have a similar issue if you start using repeaters in your forms, just slightly different.. I wonder if we can have a recursive approach when displaying in the actual error template as in http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates

Comment: It shouldn't be so painful just to get an error summary on the page ...